# function to clear the input value by newly input value after delay is not working

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a function that clears the input value by the new text I type after a 2-second delay.

At first it worked, but now for some reason, it just replaces the value of the input by the first letter of the word I typed before the delay.

Sometimes it removes the containers below the input as well.

Here is the code if you want to try for yourself :

https://codepen.io/Hautzii/pen/gOEWqjV

```
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (inputPause) { e.target.value = e.target.value.charAt(0); inputPause = false;}
  if (timeOut) clearTimeout(timeOut)
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => { inputPause = true }, 2000)
})
```

Comment: What do you think `e.target.value = e.target.value.charAt(0)` does?

Comment: I know it does that but the fact that I'm confused is because it actually worked the first time I coded it

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Basically, I type something, after a 2-second wait, I want the new input to replace the existing one, instead of having to delete it and write something on top of it

Comment: Are you asking us why the code you are **not** showing us *used to work*?

Comment: what do you mean not showing you ? I've given you the whole code, I didn't omit anything

Comment: Please make the smallest working reproducible code (with HTML etc?) as a snippet  right here - your codepen has a lot more than this.  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added logic to the setTimeout statement to fit your needs. The current input will be cleared for your new input after 2s.

EDIT: The code will now split the event target value and get the last element of it (your last input).

```
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (inputPause) { 
    e.target.value = e.target.value.split('').slice(-1);
    inputPause = false;
  }
  if (timeOut) clearTimeout(timeOut)
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => { inputPause = true }, 2000)
})
```

Comment: The outcome is the same, the input that is present before the timeout will get replaced by the first letter of that same input after the timeout

Comment: Actually it's true, I made a bad check, pretty fun to see, it might be because you've selected the first char?

Comment: Yeah but weirdly enough it actually worked the first time I tried it. No idea how I'm supposed to fix it tho. I only started JavaScript 2 weeks ago

Comment: @Hautzii This version should work ! ;)
The point is, you need to set the target value to the last input of your user. Using an hardcoded int is not working for each string length. It may have worked if you used only a letter in your tests before.

Comment: It works perfectly thanks ! Didn't know you could use split and slice like that